# Substituir uma variável dentro de um arquivo Word

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-word

Estou tentando fazer em C# (aplicação Windows Form) imprimir um Word `.doc` só que trocando alguns paramentos do tipo `@Nome` por uma *string*.

Resumindo, tenho um contrato e preciso imprimir ele. Informando campos específicos, já tenho um arquivo do Word modelo e só preciso preenche-lo com os dados.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
public void PreencherPorReplace(string CaminhoDocMatriz)
{
    //Objeto a ser usado nos parâmetros opcionais
    object missing=System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    Word.Application oApp=new Word.Application() ;

    object template = CaminhoDocMatriz;

    Word.Document oDoc = oApp.Documents.Add(ref template , ref missing,
                                            ref missing, ref missing);

    //Troca o conteúdo de alguns tags
    Word.Range oRng= oDoc.Range(ref missing ,ref missing );

    object FindText = "@Nome";
    object ReplaceWith="Teste";
    object MatchWholeWord = true;
    object Forward = false;

    oRng.Find.Execute( ref FindText, ref missing, ref MatchWholeWord,
                       ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref Forward,
                       ref missing, ref missing, ref ReplaceWith, ref missing,
                       ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);


    oApp.Visible = true;
}
```

Porem ele só substitui 1 vez o `@Nome`.

Comment: O que você já tentou e o que deu de erro?

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: Seu objeto oRng retornar todos os @Nome ele não tem um método FindAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sintaxe do método [`Find.Execute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute.aspx) é:

```
bool Execute(
    ref Object FindText,
    ref Object MatchCase,
    ref Object MatchWholeWord,
    ref Object MatchWildcards,
    ref Object MatchSoundsLike,
    ref Object MatchAllWordForms,
    ref Object Forward,
    ref Object Wrap,
    ref Object Format,
    ref Object ReplaceWith,
    ref Object Replace,
    ref Object MatchKashida,
    ref Object MatchDiacritics,
    ref Object MatchAlefHamza,
    ref Object MatchControl
)
```

No parâmetro `replace`, especifique a constante [`wdReplaceAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdreplace.aspx):

```
object replace = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;

//...

oRng.Find.Execute( ref FindText , ref missing,ref MatchWholeWord , 
                   ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref Forward,
                   ref missing,ref missing,ref ReplaceWith ,ref replace,
                   ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing);
```